# MCU connected to Doctor Who?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-who, time-travel, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In the post-credit scene of *Ant-Man and The Wasp*, Janet van Dyne tells Scott Lang:

> "Don't get sucked into a time vortex. We won't be able to save you."

Sometimes filmmakers will put in little Easter eggs like [Serenity in Battlestar Galactica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97301/did-serenity-really-appear-in-battlestar-galactica) and I was wondering if there was anything in books, comics, etc. that would explain this.

Is there a connection to the Doctor Who and the time vortex in that universe? Or are the words "time vortex" just a coincidence?

Comment: You're putting a lot of weight into two words here.

Comment: Earth-5556 Doctor.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY That's the Doctor from _Doctor Who Weekly_, no longer owned or published by Marvel now though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot When dealing with Time Lord and time vortex can we seriosuly treat "no longer" and "now"? ;)

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY [Maybe not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dcu6GEti_94).

Comment: Just google for "time vortex -who" and you will find out that there are mentions of this outside of Dr. Who....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no connection between the MCU and *Doctor Who* that I am aware of. Several actors have played characters in both but that is about it. The only other connection is that [*Doctor Who Weekly*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_Magazine) was initially published by Marvel Comics from 1979 to 1995 but not anymore.

So, no there doesn't appear to be any connection between the two and you are reading a lot into two words, especially so when the MCU loves to throw techno-babble buzzwords at things to "explain" them.

Comment: I didn't think so but it was a thought that had popped in my head and for some reason couldn't shake it. Thanks.